# How can I recover files from an XFS file system without spending money on software?

Tags: data-recovery, xfs

I have an old Iomega NAS, that has stopped working.

The drive is still good, I just need to recover the files. Both of my Ubuntu machines recognize the drives in the **Disks** utility, but I can't do anything with them beyond formatting.

- I have tried KDE partition manager with no luck, and
- I have sampled [UFS Explorer](http://www.ufsexplorer.com/) on Windows. UFS Explorer is great, but I am poor and I can't afford to buy the license.

Does Ubuntu have some open source software that will do what UFS Explorer does?

Comment: Did you try GParted?

Comment: The problem with NAS systems is that they use a specific RAID disk arrangement which will distribute the data among all the available hard disk drives and will make them work as if they were a single drive. You will be in need to emulate such behavior in a computer in order to be able to gain access to the data. You will be in the need to research a lot from your old NAS in order to know which is the best chances to reproduce the NAS behavior thus gain access to the data, after which I suggest you to run a backup.

Comment: I have not tried GParted. I will give that a try. It was a single drive NAS so it isn't a RAID issue. The data on the drive is good I'm just having difficulty getting it off of the drive because of the XFS file system. I will give GParted a shot though.

Comment: I tried GParted and it won't recognize the drive. I have also tried to boot to the XFS drive directly and it won't boot. I need a program that will read the XFS file system. The drive is still good.